# Launching Google Chrome/Opera in Kiosk Mode

Tags: windows, google-chrome, opera, kiosk

I am trying to create a desktop shortcut to launch Chrome or Opera in Kiosk Mode and to a specific URL.  I've tried adjusting the target to include /KioskMode after chrome.exe.

Does anyone know the general format?  I think I can access the directory properly because the shortcut launches the browser, so I just need to know how to launch in Kiosk to a particular URL.  This is in Windows.

Answer (score 5):

For Opera:

- Windows: C:\Program Files\Opera\opera.exe /KioskMode
- UNIX: opera -kioskmode
- Mac: Applications/Opera.app/Contents/MacOS/Opera -kioskmode

and for more explanation: [some Opera documentation about kioks mode](http://www.opera.com/support/mastering/kiosk/)

Comment: Opera Chromium seems to have removed the kioskmode on OSX and Chrome never enabled it on OSX.

Comment: `-kioskmode` is not working on Linux with version 47.0.2631.39. Neither is other flags, such as `-fullscreen`.

Answer (score 2):

(in addition to ytg's answer)

If you add your desired website URL after /kioskmode, that site will be launched in kiosk mode

`C:\Program Files\Opera\opera.exe /KioskMode www.google.de`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like `chrome url --kiosk`

Answer (score 0):

```
C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe http://www.google.com --kiosk
```

Here you are

You can do the same on Linux

```
Exec=/usr/bin/chromium-browser --noerrdialogs --disable-session-crashed-bubble --disable-infobars --kiosk http://www.google.com
```

I found a perfect tutorial but it's in French, still translatable in my opinion.
[Here](http://blog.philippegarry.com/2016/03/29/faire-de-son-pi-une-borne-raspberry-pi-kiosk-mode-jessie-version/)